# Invertible Prime in a Noetherian Scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

What means the following:

Let $\ell$ be a prime, and $X$ a Noetherian Scheme, on wich the prime $\ell$ is invertible.

The reference is the appendix of "Weil Conjectures, Perverse Sheaves and l’adic Fourier Transform" of "Kiehl, Reinhardt, Weissauer, Rainer"

Comment: It probably just means that $\ell$ is invertible in all the rings of the structure sheaf. In practice you're probably working over a field and you're just making sure that the characteristic isn't $\ell$.